# How to profile a shared object without profiling the host app?

Tags: dynamic-linking, gprof

I have a host application and I have written a plug-in.  I compile my plug-in down to a shared object (say foo.so), and the host application will load it via dlopen.  In this case, my host application is the opt tool from llvm (though I don't think that's important to the question).

I'd like to compile my plug-in with profiling enabled (i.e. `g++ -pg`, `gprof`).  However, when I do this, the profile output file gmon.out is never created.  Maybe gprof expects someone to call a setup routine, or something like that.

For various reasons, I would like to avoid recompiling the host app with -pg.  I am curious if it is possible to profile a shared object foo.so without profiling the host application opt.

I've also looked into other profiling tools; qprof from HP should be able to handle this situation, but it is unable to resolve the names of functions in the shared object (it falls back to addr2line in a very naive way).

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason you want to do this is to find ways to optimize the plugin (as opposed to just getting timing information).

Can you run the host app under a debugger or IDE? Does the IDE have a pause button, or can you interrupt it with Ctrl-C or some such key?

Then you can quickly find the costly code by using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802). Only take samples when your plugin is running, or if you can't do that, just ignore samples that don't end in your plugin.

Even if you get **gprof** to work, or a similar profiler, [you're likely to be disappointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343).